# Get only modified values

Tags: merge, adonis.js

I'm updating a model and need to return ONLY the values that were changed.

```
const data = request.only(['name', 'email', 'address', 'age'])
const user = await user.findOrFail(data.id)
user.merge({ nome: data.name, email: data.email, endereco: data.address, age: data.age })

await user.save()
```

`merge` doesn't return anything so how Could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basically, it `user.dirty` property before you `await user.save()`.**

To know what attributes were / will be updated, you need to compare the `user.$attributes` and the `user.$originalAttributes` before the user model instance `saved()`. The 'difference' stores in the `user.dirty` property after you `merge`.

This screenshot below was taken before I did `merge()`, you can see `user.$attributes` is similar to `user.$originalAttributes`, and the `user.dirty` property is empty. (user.isDirty = false)

[image]

And this screenshot was taken after I did `merge()`. The user `first_name` will be updated (to 'first name ---- changed') while the user `last_name` will be unchanged ('last name'), you can see now `user.dirty = {first_name: 'first name --- changed'}`, it contains `first_name` key and its to-be-updated value. (user.isDirty = true)

[image]

So. It is:

```
  const user = await User.findOrFail(1)

  console.log('exists user', user)

  user.merge({
    first_name: 'first name --- updated',
    last_name: 'last name'
  })

  console.log('user before updated', user)

  const output = user.isDirty ? user.dirty : {} // {} mean no attributes will be updated

  console.log('attribute that will be updated', output)

  await user.save()

  return output
```

Comment: Never will understand how this kind of thing is not in oficial documentation. Thanks!